# One Example about LL(1) Grammar?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, programming-languages, grammar, ll-grammar

I read one of my notes for Preparing PhD entrance Exam. Uppercase letter is non-terminals and Lowercase letter is terminal.

We have two grammar as like :

```
G1: S-->bSa | aSb | ba
G2: S-->XYa
    X-->a | Yb
    Y--> c | epsilon
```

My note's wrote:

`G1` is not `LL(1)` Grammar but `G2` is `LL(1)` Grammar.I know some about LL(1) but I think this example is not obvious to me. anyone could simplicit it for me? thanks.

Comment: You need to look more closely at the documentation for that online tool. Here's the grammar: http://smlweb.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/vital-stats.php?grammar=S+-%3E+b+S+a%0D%0A+++|+a+S+b%0D%0A+++|+b+a. (Spaces matter.)

Comment: @rici Okey. I get it. thanks. Is It possible to make it clearer for me without tools?

Comment: @rici your grammar has wrong syntax too, Error, line 2, syntax error found at EOF The grammar is ill-formed!

Comment: That wasn't me. It was stack overflow's html converter, which helpfully deleted the `.` at the end of the URL. You could add the `.` back yourself, or try this: http://smlweb.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/vital-stats.php?grammar=S+-%3E+b+S+a%0D%0A+++|+a+S+b%0D%0A+++|+b+a.#

Comment: Thanks @rici So my last question is How I can use Symbol Epsilon in that tools?

Comment: I have no idea. Probably, just put nothing. (eg.  `List ->  | List x.` )